# phalcon asset manager doesn't copy assets to a specific directory

Tags: php, assets, phalcon

I am trying to load assets using asset manager in phalcon but I want all the assets to be copied into a public assets directory. Since phalcon only copies if there is a filter bind to a collection, I added `\Filter\None` to the set of filters but I keep getting "Target path is invalid" which I have no idea why exists. Here is what I have done:

```
$di->set('assets', function() {
     $assets = new Phalcon\Assets\Manager([
          'output'=>realpath(__DIR__.'/assets/'),
          'compileAlways'=>false,
          'stat'=>true
      ]);
      return $assets;
});

  // controller
$css = new \Phalcon\Assets\Resource\Css('/assets/style.css');
$css->setSourcePath(realpath($this->view->getViewsDir().'/../../assets/style.css'));
$css->setTargetPath(APP_PATH.'/assets/style.css');
$css->setLocal(false);
$this->assets->addResourceByType('css', $css);

// view
$this->assets->outputCss();
```

and a test directory structure:

```
/application
        /public
                /assets
                index.php
        /themes
                /default
                        /css
                            style.css
```

The directory permissions are set to 777 (I am on a *NIX system), for testing purposes. What should I do?

Comment: Print `$css->getTargetPath()` and `$css->getSourcePath()` in your controller to check paths.

Comment: Source and Target paths are shown correctly. However, it doesn't create any files in the target path with `Filters\None`

Comment: I think I am going to write my own asset manager for this one. Thanks anyways

Comment: Should the target path be `APP_PATH . '/public/assets/style.css' `